# Using Thunderbird, how can one attach from command line a file containing commas (,) in its name?

Tags: linux, command-line, thunderbird, gnu

`thunderbird -compose "attachment='$HOME/test test.txt'"` works.
`thunderbird -compose "attachment='$HOME/test, test.txt'"` does not work and gives a `file does not exist` error message.

This must be because of the way Thunderbird handles command line arguments; e.g.,

`thunderbird -compose "to='name@mail.com',attachment='~/file.txt'"`

The `compose` arguments are separated by `,` and that must be why having a `,` in the file name breaks things. I cannot, however, think of a way to "escape" commas in the file name.

Note:

- In Thunderbird 3+, using the protocol `file://` is not required any more.

Both

`thunderbird -compose "attachment='$HOME/test test.txt'"`

and

`thunderbird -compose "attachment='file://$HOME/test test.txt'"`

work.

Neither

`thunderbird -compose "attachment='$HOME/test, test.txt'"`

nor

`thunderbird -compose "attachment='file://$HOME/test, test.txt'"`

works.

Comment: At a guess I would suggest trying to escape `\,` or url encode `%2C` it.

Comment: Escaping comma (`\,`) does not work; it gives the same `file does not exist error`. The characters `,` and `%` are both legitimate in the file name so I don't think URL encoding is an option because `test,test` and `test%2Ctest` are both legitimate file names.

Comment: While true `test%2Ctest` would become `test%252Ctest` when url encoded. It is worth trying it (it might need the explicit `file://` prefix to work I suppose but I don't know).

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the wrapper script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the idea of URL encoding the file names suggested by @Etan Reisner (in a comment to my question above), I hacked a solution which I record here for the benefit of others in the community. In the snippet below, `${filename}` is the full file name (including path) to be attached.

```
#!/bin/bash

# "A safe way to URL encode is to encode every single byte, even
# those that would've been allowed." This is done by first
# converting every byte to its 2-byte hex code using `hexdump' and
# then adding the prefix `%' to each 2-byte hex code pair using
# `sed'.
#
# Attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506695

filenameurlencoded=$(echo -ne "${filename}" | \
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"' | \
sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g')

filenamenopath="$(basename ${filename})"
emailsubject="${filenamenopath}"
emailbody="\"${filenamenopath}\" is attached."
emailattachment="file:///${filenameurlencoded}"

# Syntax of -compose command line option: double-quotes enclose
# full comma-separated list of arguments passed to -compose,
# whereas single quotes are used to group items for the same
# argument.
#
# Attribution: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_(Thunderbird)

thunderbird -compose "subject='${emailsubject}',body='${emailbody}',attachment='${emailattachment}'"
```